# SVG: CSS properties are not applied

Tags: css, svg

I have a HTML 5 file containing a SVG element. Also there are some styles defined in a CSS file (imported in the html file correctly), e.g.:

```
rect.cell-border {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width:1.3px;   
}
```

One element in the SVG looks like this:

```
<rect class="cell cell-border" width="256" height="256" style="fill-opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
```

Problem: Besides the inline CSS properties this rect element does not get the properties by cell-border. I have absolutely no idea why. In general the CSS file works, because other (non SVG but pure HTML) elements are styled correctly.
I generate the SVG elements with D3.

Comment: I don't think `px` is a valid value for this, as a pixel means nothing to an SVG...

Comment: Do you get the svg through the <img> tag or do you dump the entire <svg></svg> data from the file into the html document?

Comment: px **is** a valid CSS unit for stroke-width

Comment: the svg is already in the html file and its contents, e.g., the rect elements, are created with D3.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the solution that finally worked was to include the external css file in a different way:

```
<style>
       @import url(css/MatrixVisualization.css)
</style>
```

Rather than the regular way. Another possibility would be to use embedded css declarations.

Comment: I'll be a bit pedantic here, but `@import` is known to have load performance issues in certain browsers (sequential instead of parallel loading) therefore embedded `<style>` could be a more performant option

Answer (score 1):

It works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j0g8rnqu/1/

This means that your css and the svg are correct. There can only be something wrong with your binding of the css file. If you do it the standard way, it should work. Here is the most simple case:

**`file test.html`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="svg-test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" overflow="visible">
      <rect class="cell cell-border" width="256" height="256" style="fill: #79a;"></rect>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`file svg-test.css`**

```
rect.cell-border {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width:1.3px;   
}
```

Note that I added `overflow="hidden"`to the svg to ensure that the border does not get cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me. The first rect has the class and therefore the stroke, the bottom does not.

```css
rect.cell-border {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width:1.3px;   
}
```

```html
<svg height="258" width="258" viewBox="-1 -1 258 258">
  <rect class="cell cell-border" width="256" height="256" style="fill-opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
</svg>

<svg height="258" width="258" viewBox="-1 -1 258 258">
  <rect width="256" height="256" style="fill-opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's interesting: If I declare the styles in my index.html rather than an external file it just works fine.. Does this refer to the other answer which states that we need a special "include" for a css file to be applied within a svg?

Comment: Exactly how are you including the CSS file and how are you including the SVG? Is the SVG inline like I've got it?

Comment: @pedjjj Also check the mime-type of the external CSS file. If that's wrong it won't get used.